# Django REST:Combine two models

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I just started using django rest framework and this might be an old question, but so far I haven't found any proper answer to it on SO.

I want to add some extra profile fields to the existing User model the DRF provided. Having read the document, I chose to create a new CustomUser model and associate it with the default User model by foreign key.

The question came when I was trying to serialize the CustomUser model. I want the json to be like this:

```
{
  "username" : "from_default_user_model",
  "extra_field" : "from_custom_user_model"
}
```

but by using nested serializers as following, I got nested json representation.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user  = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('extra_field',)
```

The nested one looks like this:

```
{
    "username" : "from_default_user_model",
    "user" : 
           {
               "extra_field" : "from_custom_user_model"
           }
}
```

What I want is some kind like a database join between two tables, which simply yields a plain table, rather than the nested one. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're going to use Django's default User model as an OneToOneField with your custom User Model. You don't need another serializer for User model. Since extra fields will be in CustomUser, it's enough to write a serializer for only Custom User.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # Add your extra fields here.
```

This is how you do it:

```
CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = Serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    email = Serializers.EmailField(source='user.email')

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'extra_fields_from_CustomUser',)
```

Thankfully, `source` lets you to reach your OneToOneField easily so that you don't need anything else.

Comment: This solves my problem but specifying the type of each field again might be a bit tedious, especially when you are not sure about the original field type. For example, you have to specify `last_login = serializer.DateTimeField(source='user.last_login')` rather than `DateField(source='user.last_login')`. The latter will give you an assertion failure.

Comment: Yes that might be tedious but you'll do it for only User model,  therefore it's not too much extra work.

Answer (score 2):

On the CustomUser model, create a shortcut property, then add it to the fields definition in meta

```
@property
def username(self):
    return self.user.username

class meta:
    model = ...
    fields = ("username", "extra-field",...)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate it a bit more? I got an **ImproperlyConfigured** error while trying out your answer, thanks.